speed up python function
I want to simulate a rectangular mesh made of particles connected with linear springs. One of the functions that i have is shown below. I use it to find the distances between particles and a vector of length 1 between the connected particles.
xv,yv and  zv, are 1xn arrays with the x,y and z positions of the particles. cons is a n by n array of booleans indicating if two particles are connected or not. so e.g if cons[i,j]=True, then particle i and j are connected by a spring.
I want to run this code for n=62500 which makes the arrays very large and the code slow. Do you have any suggestions to improve this?
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix as sparse

def getDistance(xv,yv,zv,cons):
    
    dx=xv-xv.T
    dy=yv-yv.T 
    dz=zv-zv.T
    
   
    dl=sparse((len(dx),len(dx)),dtype=np.float32).toarray()
    dl[cons]+=np.sqrt(dx[cons]**2+dy[cons]**2+dz[cons]**2)
    
    normx=sparse((len(xv),len(xv)),dtype=np.float32).toarray()
    normy=sparse((len(yv),len(yv)),dtype=np.float32).toarray()
    normz=sparse((len(zv),len(zv)),dtype=np.float32).toarray()
    
    normx[cons]=dx[cons]/dl[cons]
    normy[cons]=dy[cons]/dl[cons]
    normz[cons]=dz[cons]/dl[cons]
    return normx,normy,normz,dl

